# Macro or VBA code for collating data

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a task of collating data from 20 or 22 text files in excel however, 99%of time I will have data in text delimited format but 1%chance that out of the 20odd text files 1 file will have the data formatted using text to column function when u test check it while opening the text files in excel. My query is, is there a way to build a macro which checks the data before collating everything in one sheet and exclude that 1 file where the data is already formatted using text to column.Unable to attach the screen shots of the data files. Please let me know if u need them I will mail them separately
Please find the code that I am currently using

```
Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"

' work through sheets
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count ' from sheet 2 to last sheet
Sheets(J).Activate ' make the sheet active
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select ' select all cells in this sheets

' copy cells selected in the new sheet on last line
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1000000").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks YowE3K, I already have a macro ( got it from one of the forums) to collate the data however, in the last month we encountered a one off situation where the data was in a different format( it was already formatted with rows and columns ) so I want to build a check that while collating the data it excludes such one off's which can then added manually in the collated data .

Comment: The code that I am currently using is.                              Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"

' work through sheets
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count ' from sheet 2 to last sheet
Sheets(J).Activate ' make the sheet active
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select ' select all cells in this sheets

' copy cells selected in the new sheet on last line
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1000000").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub

Comment: Done now the code is with the question

Comment: Thanks Amit - I have formatted it to make it look "nice" - hopefully someone will come along and help you now.  (Unfortunately, I'm about to go home from work now, so won't have a chance to help myself.)

Comment: Thanks YowE3K for the help